# How to give names to range of integers in dart?

Tags: dart

I would like to save properties in a list. So I want to access the list items by property name.

Now I use the following approach:

```
enum Scooter { power, capacity, model }

void main() {
  final scooter = [50, 1000, "Suzuki"];
  print(scooter[Scooter.model.index]);
}
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: A better way is to not store properties in a `List`, which loses type information and therefore loses type-safety.  Define a class with explicit fields instead.  Or use `Record`s from Dart 3.

Comment: @jamesdlin you are right, but lists take less storage space in firestore than maps. It is the only reason why I prefer list in my particular case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use constants.

```dart
const scooterPower = 0;
const scooterCapacity = 1;
const scooterModel = 2;

void main() {
  final scooter = [50, 1000, "Suzuki"];
  print(scooter[ScooterModel]);
}
```

Or use helper functions:

```dart
int scooterPower(List<dynamic> list) => list[0];
int scooterCapacity(List<dynamic> list) => list[1];
String scooterModel(List<dynamic> list) => list[2];

void main() {
  final scooter = [50, 1000, "Suzuki"];
  print(scooterModel(scooter));
}
```

Or, if static helper functions is too last millenium, use extension getters:

```dart
extension ScooterProperties on List<dynamic> {
  int get scooterPower => this[0];
  int get scooterCapacity => this[1];
  String get scooterModel => this[2];
}

void main() {
  final scooter = [50, 1000, "Suzuki"];
  print(scooter.scooterModel);
}
```

In every case, you have no static type safety, and will get runtime errors if you use any of the access method on something which is not actually a "valid scooter list".

In the next version of Dart, you can use patterns, and more concisely do a few more tests, like:

```dart
extension ScooterProperties on List<dynamic> {
  int get scooterPower {
    if (this case [int power, int _, String _]) return power;
    throw StateError("Not a scooter list");
  }
  int get scooterCapacity {
    if (this case [int _, int capacity, String _]) return capacity;
    throw StateError("Not a scooter list");
  }
  String get scooterModel {
    if (this case [int _, int _, String model]) return model;
    throw StateError("Not a scooter list");
  }
}

void main() {
  final scooter = [50, 1000, "Suzuki"];
  print(scooter.scooterModel);
}
```

A little further into the future, you may be able to use inline classes to cheaply wrap the list.

```dart
inline class Scooter {
  final List<dynamic> _list;
  Scooter(List<dynamic> list) : _list = list;
    if (list case [int _, int _, String _]) return;
    throw ArgumentError.value(list, "list", "Not a valid scooter list");
  }
  int get power => _list[0];
  int get capacity => _list[1];
  String get model => _list[2]; 
}

void main() {
  final scooter = Scooter([50, 1000, "Suzuki"]);
  print(scooter.model);
}
```

(Until then you can also use a non-`inline` class to do the same thing.)